# Java Selector NIO Reading problem

Tags: java, selector, nio

Relevant Code
-- Note Instructions is merely a class with several methods which will operate on the data. A new thread is created operate on the data read.

READ THREAD:

```
while(true) {
     System.out.println(".");
     if(selector.select(500) == 0)
          continue;

     System.out.println("processing read");

     for(SelectionKey sk : selector.keys()) {
          Instructions ins = myHashTable.get(sk);
          if(ins == null) { 
               myHashTable.put(sk, new Instructions(sk));
               ins = myHashTable.get(sk);
          }
          ins.readChannel();
     }
}
```

READCHANNEL

```
public void readChannel() {
     BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(Channels.newReader((ReadableByteChannel) this.myKey.channel(), "UTF-8"));
     Worker w = new Worker(this, reader.readLine());
     (new Thread(w)).start();
}
```

The new thread then calls more `Instructions` methods.

When the ins function finishes it *might* write to a Writer:

```
Writer out = Channels.newWriter((WritableByteChannel) key.channel(), "UTF-8");
out.write(output);
out.flush();
```

I can confirm that my client (a flash movie), then receives and acts on the output.

Finally, `w` exits.

After the receipt of the first message from the client, and successful processing, however, no more messages are taken care of by the `READ THREAD` loop. I believe the key is registered with the selector and ready to read. I have checked by looping on all the keys to see if they are readable with isReadable & isRegistered on the channel and the result is true in all cases to date. When a second message is sent from the client, however, the only response I see in the read thread is that the '.' character is printed out not every half second, but continuously faster. I believe, then, that the data is there in the channel, but for some reason the Selector isn't selecting any key.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3):

I think you are missing few points here.

- Firstly, you should use the selector.selectedKeys() in the for loop
  as mentioned by Vijay.
- One should remove the key from selectedKeys
  after the key is processed. Otherwise, the key will not be
  removed automatically and hence selector might spin continuously even
  if there is one key with    interested ops bit set. (This might be
  the issue in your case).
- Finally, we should perform operations on
  channel    if the    channel is ready for it. i.e, read only if
  isReadable() returns true    and try to write only if isWritable() is
  true. Don't forget to    validate the key.

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't

```
for(SelectionKey sk : selector.keys())
```

be

```
for(SelectionKey sk : selector.selectedKeys())
```

Since you would like to process only those events that have occurred in the current select operation ?

Since you say that the select(500) returns before 5 seconds, my guess is that you have registered a channel with the selector for the WRITE operation. A channel is ready for write most of the times. Hence it is necessary to set the interest ops to WRITE only when data is available for writing.

Answer (score 0):

Note that you have to remove the channel from the list of selected keys. Select() won't do that for you. Better to use iterator for this purpose:

```
Iterator<SelectionKey> key_interator = selector.selectedKeys().iterator();
while (key_interator.hasNext()) {
  ...
  key_interator.remove();
}
```

Comment: an other way to do this is to get the key set iterate over it with the foreach loop and call the clear() method on the set after the loop.